# React - What is the best way to change an elements text each time the user clicks anywhere on screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've started learning React, and after having read through the documentation, have a question..

I want to do the following:

I want to render text as part of a component. Then when a user clicks anywhere on the screen, the text changes, then changes again on a second click, and then again on a third, and finally, a fourth click.

I'd like to know what best practice would be when doing this in react? I was thinking about using the 'onClick' method, but that would only allow for two states?

Some assistance would be very much appreciated to help me on my react journey.

```js
const welcome = <h1>Welcome to my app 1/4</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(
  welcome,
  document.getElementById('theapp')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  <title>Learn ReactJS</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react-course-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/app.compiled.js"></script>

  <div id="theapp"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not keep a counter in the state and update it on every click. So you will have the track of number of clicks. OnClick will update your text as well as your counter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Vivek, I will look at implementing your idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know you want exactly 4 messages, create an array containing them. Then, on each click update a counter which is then used to fetch the relevant item from the array.

Check the demos below.

---

#### Message change on `<h1>` click

This snippet has a counter/index and an array with the messages to display defined in the initial state. We are then adding an eventlistener to the h1 element to trigger on click. Doing so increases the index as long as it's not greater than 2 (at which point there are no more messages left to display).

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      messages: ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"],
      index: 0
    };
    this.incrementCounter = this.incrementCounter.bind(this);
  }
  
  incrementCounter() {
    if(this.state.index > 2) return;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({index: prevState.index + 1}));
  }
  
  render() {
    return <h1 onClick={this.incrementCounter}>{this.state.messages[this.state.index]}</h1>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

#### Message change on `window` click

Similar to the previous example, here we are adding the listener to the window object itself. We need to do this in the componentDidMount method.

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      messages: ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"],
      index: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if(this.state.index > 2) return;
      this.setState((prevState) => ({index: prevState.index + 1}));
    }.bind(this));
  }
  
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.state.messages[this.state.index]}</h1>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for your answer! And I guess this could be flexible in that if I wanted to add/remove messages to/from the array, then I'd just need to make sure I update the listener so that the index can be increased or decreased as per how many messages I have.

Comment: No, if you want to add/remove messages from the array change the condition to `this.state.index > this.state.index.length-2`. This way it's more flexible.

Comment: Thanks Chris, appreciate the help on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mousedown` event to observe clicks anywhere on the screen like

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        count: 0,
        message: ["message1", "message2", "message3", "message4"]
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', this.pageClick.bind(this), false);
    }

    pageClick(e) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            if(prevState.count != this.state.message.length - 1)
                return { count: prevState.count + 1};
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { message, count } = this.state;
        return (
            <h1>Welcome to my app {message[count]}</h1>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Welcome/>, 
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

You can use `mouseup` and `click` events also.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your texts in array like :

```
 const data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

Than everytime when user clicks, increment the state i by 1.

```
import React from 'react';

const data = ['one', 'two', 'three']

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        name: 'hello',
        i : 0
      }
   }
   click(){
       // if it's the last element of array than it will start from 0 index again
       if(data[this.state.i] == undefined){
          this.setState({i : 0})
       }
       setTimeout(function() { this.setState({name: data[this.state.i], i : this.state.i + 1 }); }.bind(this), 50);
       // incrementing counter by 1 everytime user clicks

   }
   render() {

      return (
         <div>
             <div>
               <span>{this.state.name}</span>
               <button onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>Click</button>
             </div>

         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```